# Tap area of UIBarButtonItem is smaller than its CustomView

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, uibarbuttonitem

I have a UIBarButtonItem with a UIView inside (let's say *container*) containing a UIImageView and another UIView for showing notification state. The container also has a UITapGestureRecognizer. But the problem is that taps work only in a small area of this view. I set constraints and frame size for the container, but it didn't work. What may cause the issue and how can I resolve it?

[image: UIBarButtonItem with a tap area]

Comment: please share some code, plus you might solve the issue by changing height and width

Comment: Here's my C# code:

`var imageView = new UIImageView(UIImage.FromBundle("account"));`

`var container = new UIView(new CGRect(0, 0, 40, 40));`

`container.AddSubview(imageView);`

`var barButtonItem = new UIBarButtonItem(container);`

`NavigationItem.SetRightBarButtonItem(barButtonItem, true);`

I tried to set the width for the UIBarButtonItem, but it didn't help.

Comment: What if it because the dimensions of the nee CGRect that your creating